# how to use php to write html tag to another html file?

Tags: php, html, writefile

I have two files. One is input.php, the other is output.html.
Inner input.php file the code is like:

```
<?php

   $file="output.html";
   $doc=new DOMDocument('1.0');
   $doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
   $elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('head');

   $jscript=$doc->createElement("script");
   $jstype=$doc->createAttribute("type");
   $jstText=$doc->createTextNode("text/javascript");
   $jstype->appendChild($jstText);
   $jscript->appendChild($jstype);
   $jssource=$doc->createAttribute("src");
   $jssText=$doc->createTextNode("xxxxx.js");
   $jssource->appendChild($jssText);
   $jscript->appendChild($jssource);
   $elements->item(0)->appendChild($jscript);
   $doc->save("output.html");   
?>
```

in the output.html file:

```
<code>   
 <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
 </html>
</code>
```

Actually, I want add the  under output.html's "head". But now there are two problems.

1.even though the content can be written in the output.php fle, but it always get  in the first line of the file, it makes the html page does not work.

2.the  tag is always added as . (xml format). it does not work, I need  (a html format)

Is there any solution for the 2 problems? Or is there any other way to achieve my goal? (in the input.php file I tried saveHTML()-still not work)

Comment: Did you try `saveHTMLFile()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation

> DOMDocument::save — Dumps the **internal XML tree** back into a file

So no wonder you get a XML representation. You should try `DOMDocument::saveHTMLFile` as has already been suggested in the comments or you could try `echo $doc->saveHTML();`